# Sufficient lag time for workbooks to calculate when open for data extraction

Tags: excel, vba

I have encountered this problem: I wrote a simple macro to open multiple workbooks (one by one) to extract data from certain cells. These workbooks are all similar in structure. Now, sometimes it seems that the workbook being open does not have sufficient time for the calculation in the cells to be completed before the macro extract the values. It means what the macro extracts is erroneous such as "#VALUE" or "#NAME". But when open manually, the cells are calculated perfectly.

Is there a way to wait for calculation of the opened workbook to complete before the macro extracts the values? Is there a "wait" function?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Wait`, but it probably will freeze Excel's execution.  This will insure a 2 second wait between opening a workbook and the final `MsgBox`:

```
Sub WaitABit()
    Dim d As Date

    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\beta.xlsx"

    d = Now
    Do Until Now > d + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2)
        DoEvents
    Loop
    MsgBox "X"
End Sub
```

The `DoEvents` allows focus to be shared between VBA and Excel.

Comment: use of CTRL/ALT/F9 , can it help any way

Comment: @skkakkar  You are correct!...................but the poster wanted it in the *VBA*

Comment: Thank you, Gary's Student. It actually stop the Excel and just freezes like you said. Also, my task is to extract hundreds of files, or even thousand, for this purpose on a network drive. This seems to take too long if each file requires even one second wait. But I learn something new here !

Answer (score 1):

Would the `Application.AfterCalculation` event be useful to you (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225813(v=office.12).aspx)?

For example, you could create a calculation listener class that fires an event whenever your calculations are complete. This listener could be re-set each time a book is opened and you could simply handle the event each time. The class might look something like this (insert a new class and call it something appropriate, I named mine `CalcListener`):

```
Public Event OnTargetCalculationsComplete()
Private WithEvents mApp As Application
Private mHandled As Boolean
Private mCalculationState As Integer

Public Sub FlagSheetsAsUncalculated(ParamArray targetSheets() As Variant)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim calculationState As Integer

    'Set the handled flag to false so event is captured.
    mHandled = False

    'Disable autocalculation.
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Toggle the EnableCalculation values for each sheet.
    'Flags sheet as requiring calculation.
    For Each v In targetSheets
        Set ws = v
        ws.EnableCalculation = False
        ws.EnableCalculation = True
    Next

    'Force calculation.
    Application.Calculate

    'Restore calculation state.
    Application.Calculation = mCalculationState

End Sub

Private Sub mApp_AfterCalculate()
    'Handle the event if flag is false
    If Not mHandled Then
        'Toggle the handled flag and fire the event.
        mHandled = True
        RaiseEvent OnTargetCalculationsComplete
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mApp = Application
    'Save the calculation state.
    mCalculationState = Application.Calculation
    'Disable autocalculation.
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
```

You could create a second extracter class which opened the workbooks and did its magic only when each `OnTargetCalculationsComplete` was fired. In this example I created a new class and named it `ValueExtracter`:

```
Private WithEvents mCalcListener As CalcListener

Private Sub mCalcListener_OnTargetCalculationsComplete()
    'This routine will be called just once when the
    'target sheets have calculated.

    'Put your code here that should follow the calculation
    MsgBox "Calculations on target sheet(s) are complete"
    '...'

End Sub

Public Sub OpenBooks()
    Dim bk As Workbook

    'Instantiate the calculation listener
    Set mCalcListener = New CalcListener

    'Run your loop here to open the workbooks.
    'This example has just one workbook.

    Set bk = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\User\Documents\StackOverflow\events.xlsm")

    'Set the sheets that you wish to (re-)calculate.
    With bk.Worksheets
        mCalcListener.FlagSheetsAsUncalculated .Item(1), .Item("Sheet2")
    End With

End Sub
```

To run it, simply add the following code to your module:

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Dim oValueExtracter As ValueExtracter

    Set oValueExtracter = New ValueExtracter
    oValueExtracter.OpenBooks
End Sub
```

It is a bit of a modularised example because others might want just the listener part of the code, but you could lump it all into one class if you wished.

Comment: Thank you, Ambie. I will give this a try and let you know. Really appreciate your advice !